# Meteor -mysql methods are not returning the records

Tags: mysql, meteor

I am new to Meteor, I am using MySQL database instead of MongoDB. I want to return mysql records from one of the Meteor Method at server and I am try to return same and at client side I want to print them into console. But it is printing as 'undefined'.

[image]

```
server.js
----------

    import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
    import mysql from 'mysql';
    import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
     Meteor.methods({
        insertJobCurrent:function(EMPLID,callback) {

            var pool = mysql.createConnection({
                host: '127.0.0.1',
                user: 'root',
                password: 'abc1234',
                database: 'dbEmployees'
                //port: '31597'
            });        

            var JobCurrent=[];
            pool.query("SELECT A.EMPLID, B.NAME, A.JOBCODE, A.DEPTID, A.JOB_ENTRY_DT, A.SUPERVISOR_ID FROM Employee A JOIN names B ON A.EMPLID=B.EMPLID WHERE A.ACTIVE='Y' AND A.EMPL_RCD=0 AND A.EMPLID='"+EMPLID +"'", function (error, results, fields){

                console.log(results); // Printing the results in Meteor console
                return results;


            });

            //return jobCurrent.find().fetch();
        }
    });



client.js
--------
    Meteor.call('insertJobCurrent',employeeID, function(err, response){
            if (err) {
                console.log("error: "+ err);
                console.log(response);
            } else{

                console.log(response); // Printing undefined
                console.log("success")
            }
        });
```

How can get the results at client side? Appreciate if anyone help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a classic return value from callback problem:
[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

I'm not sure how familiar you are with callbacks and asynchronous code, but the general flow of your function currently is:

```
** Method comes in
Create db connection
>> Send async query to mysql
** function ends and returns empty message to client -> client sees empty response
<< async function finishes and runs callback, result goes nowhere because response was already sent to client.
```

What you want to do is *wait* for the callback to finish first.

There’s three ways you can do this with Meteor

#### 1. Use `Meteor.wrapAsync`

```
    insertJobCurrent: function(EMPLID,callback) {

        var pool = mysql.createConnection({
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            user: 'root',
            password: 'abc1234',
            database: 'dbEmployees'
            //port: '31597'
        });
        // Wrap the function you want to call
        // The second parameter sets `this` in the wrapped function.
        // I have no idea if the mysql module you're using needs this, but I'm including it just in case
        const wrappedmysqlQuery = Meteor.wrapAsync(pool.query, pool);

        // Now you can call the wrapped function as though it was synchronous
        const results = wrappedmysqlQuery("SELECT A.EMPLID, B.NAME, A.JOBCODE, A.DEPTID, A.JOB_ENTRY_DT, A.SUPERVISOR_ID FROM Employee A JOIN names B ON A.EMPLID=B.EMPLID WHERE A.ACTIVE='Y' AND A.EMPL_RCD=0 AND A.EMPLID='"+EMPLID +"'")
        console.log(results); // Printing the results in Meteor console
        return results;
    }
```

Here's the docs on `Meteor.wrapAsync`:
https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-wrapAsync

Long before Promises and async functions, Meteor provided sync style async calls on the server using `Fibers`. If you're curious, you can get a rundown here: https://benjamn.github.io/goto2015-talk/#/

#### 2. Return a Promise:

```
    insertJobCurrent: function(EMPLID,callback) {

        var pool = mysql.createConnection({
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            user: 'root',
            password: 'abc1234',
            database: 'dbEmployees'
            //port: '31597'
        });

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { 
            pool.query("SELECT A.EMPLID, B.NAME, A.JOBCODE, A.DEPTID, A.JOB_ENTRY_DT, A.SUPERVISOR_ID FROM Employee A JOIN names B ON A.EMPLID=B.EMPLID WHERE A.ACTIVE='Y' AND A.EMPL_RCD=0 AND A.EMPLID='"+EMPLID +"'", function (error, results, fields) {

                console.log(results); // Printing the results in Meteor console
                resolve(results);
            });
        }))

}
```

This works because Meteor checks if you're returning a promise from a method and will automatically await the result before sending it to the client

#### 3. Use Async/Await

`async functions` and `async/await` work best in when the library you're using already returns promises or if you can promisify the function in question.
I have't checked if `mysql` can return promises, so I'll use the `pify` module to promisify the function in the example

```
import pify from 'pify'

    insertJobCurrent: async function(EMPLID,callback) {

        var pool = mysql.createConnection({
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            user: 'root',
            password: 'abc1234',
            database: 'dbEmployees'
            //port: '31597'
        });
        // promisify the function you want to call
        const wrappedmysqlQuery = pify(pool.query);

        // Now when we run the promisified function it returns a promise that we
        // can wait for the value of with `await`
        const results = await wrappedmysqlQuery("SELECT A.EMPLID, B.NAME, A.JOBCODE, A.DEPTID, A.JOB_ENTRY_DT, A.SUPERVISOR_ID FROM Employee A JOIN names B ON A.EMPLID=B.EMPLID WHERE A.ACTIVE='Y' AND A.EMPL_RCD=0 AND A.EMPLID='"+EMPLID +"'");

        console.log(results); // Printing the results in Meteor console
        return results;
    }
```

Note that `await` is only available inside an `async function`. `async` functions always return a promise.

This one is most similar to the Meteor example, except that it uses pure javascript.
One notable difference is that when Meteor sees an async function it acts as though you ran `this.unblock()` inside the function, and so the order in which methods are called is not guarenteed (unlike with `wrapAsync`).